# RestFB any idea how can i know the uploading progress of the video?

Tags: java, restfb

I want to post a video with Rest FB

```
try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("MySuperFile"));
        FacebookType response = facebookClient.publish(user.getId()+"/videos", FacebookType.class,
                                                BinaryAttachment.with("formatOfMySuperVideo",fis),
                                                Parameter.with("description","TheDescriptionOfMySuperVideo"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ea) {}
```

it works very well BUT i would like to know if it's possible to know the "status" of the uploading. I mean i would like to have a progress bar or the percentage or something like that.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

First all you need to do another request in order to get the video fields. I mean after you did publish request you should get a postId, in that way the next step to do is:

```
Video video  facebookClient.fetchObject(response.getId(),Video.class, Parameter.with("fields", "status"));
```

And maybe test with a debug:

```
logger.debug("Progress... " + video.getStatus().getProcessingProgress());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your publish method will return an instance of a Video i think, where you can find the source code here :
[Video.java](https://github.com/restfb/restfb/blob/master/source/library/com/restfb/types/Video.java)

Also check response is the correct type :

```
if (response instanceof Video)
    // Do Something
```

You can now get the video status : 
[Video.java#L644](https://github.com/restfb/restfb/blob/master/source/library/com/restfb/types/Video.java#L644)

```
Video video = (Video) response;
response.getStatus().getProcessingProgress(); // Contain a percentage
```

**Edit** : It look you have to change your code a bit to get a Video :

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("MySuperFile"));
    Video response = facebookClient.publish(user.getId()+"/videos", Video.class, BinaryAttachment.with("formatOfMySuperVideo",fis), Parameter.with("description","TheDescriptionOfMySuperVideo"));
    response.getStatus().getProcessingProgress(); // Contain the upload percentage
} catch (FileNotFoundException ea) {}
```

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work :( I've a NullPointerException because the "reponse" is null

Comment: Without my changes, in your original code, what the response.getType() return ?

Comment: the response is "null" when i do response.getType()

Comment: Also `facebookClient.publish()` fail ? :O

Comment: no the `facebookClient.publish` works well but the return of this function is null :/

Comment: Open a ticket on their github also, it's a problem with the library